# Notice field on questions may be absent?

Tags: bug, questions, documentation, meta

The [notice type](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/notice), that is a field of a [question](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question), appears to be optional, yet it is not marked as "may be absent"?

For example, when I request questions with a filter that has the notice field checked, [not one seems to actually return the field](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#order=desc&sort=activity&filter=!Pw)uU(3C7Kb3SII2)E)3YNmxmpOu5r&site=stackoverflow&run=true).

Is this a mistake in the documentation or am I misinterpreting it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, officially this is a documentation bug.  From [the *Absent Fields* doc](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/absent-fields):

> Fields that are not always guaranteed to be set... are indicated in the per-type documentation. **Any discrepency(sic) between observed behavior and the documentation should be reported on Stack Apps.**

(Emphasis added and note that "discrepancy" is mispellerized. ;) )

---

### `notice` obviously should have the `may be absent` flag.

I eyeballed all of the other properties of [type question](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question), as well as [type answer](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/answer) and [type user](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user).  I didn't spot any other obvious discrepancies with the `may be absent` flag.

---

Re:

> The notice type, that is a field of a question, appears to be optional, yet it is not marked as "may be absent"?

Optional and `may be absent` are separate dimensions.

- "Optional" -- means you must craft/use a custom filter to get the property.
- "May be absent" -- means that even if called for by the filter, the property will still not be returned if the property's value is null for that particular question.